# Changing protocol handler in google chrome, opening a Telegram link

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, xdg, telegram, protocol

I installed [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/) for Linux 64-bit. To join a Telegram channel, when a channel URL is opened in google chrome (e.g. `telegram.me/channel_name`) the browser prompts and asks which application should handle the protocol.

But it has chosen `xdg-open` as default and there's no way to change it. By clicking "Lunch Application", nothing happens. How could I pass this request to Telegram application?

[image: Chrome prompted]

After all if there's any way to join a channel through Telegram desktop app directly, I would like to know it.

**Edit:**

This is the content of `.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram Desktop
Comment=Official desktop version of Telegram messaging app
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/Telegram/Telegram -- %u
Icon=/home/user/.TelegramDesktop/tdata/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
MimeType=application/x-xdg-protocol-tg;x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Comment: Do you have a telegram channel I could test with?

Comment: @Seth Here's a sample: https://telegram.me/bbcnewsbot. Thanks

Comment: Strange. It works for me. Please edit the contents of `$HOME/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` into your question. Thanks!

Comment: That's very strange. It has all the right settings AFAICT. It took maybe 2 minutes for it to launch telegram for me. Try clicking "launch application" again. Are you sure it doesn't work within about 5 minutes?

Comment: @Seth Within 5 mins? I have not borne that much actually. Is your telegram app running before clicking "launch application?" Should I leave work and switching between different apps until telegram is opened?

Comment: Mine wasn't running yet, no. It took about 1 minute and a half/2 minutes.

Comment: @Seth 5 minutes waiting and same thing. Nothing happened. I just left the tab of the telegram channel page opened in chrome and did other stuff on other tabs and apps. That looks very strange and like a horrible crime story to me now :D

Comment: The only difference between my file and yours is I have the line `StartupWMClass=Telegram` under `Terminal=false`. Try adding it and see what happens.

Comment: @Seth No that didn't work either. I'll try it again after a reboot, tomorrow. I really appreciate your patience and magnanimity in helping me. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?